# What could cause black residue on ceiling where a lightbulb had been?

Tags: light-fixture, light-bulb

I am moved into a very old house two years ago, and I have recently decided to go ahead and start replacing lightbulbs. Today I removed and 11 white light bulb from its place in a ceiling light, and I noticed that there is a black mark in the spot where the lightbulb would’ve been close to the ceiling. I know other lightbulbs in the house are only nine whites, and I am curious to know if the wattage on this light bulb was too high or if there is another reason why a black mark would have been left behind. I do not know when the last time this lightbulb have been replaced but it’s going to be at least two years ago minimum.

Comment: What is an "11 white" and a "9 white"?  Speech to text in your phone?   You can [edit] your question but must use the same browser you asked in initially (or register your account from that original browser).

Answer (score 6):

Heat from light bulbs causes a column of rising warm air.  This carries dust to the ceiling.  Over many years it causes staining above the bulb.  Your current bulbs, 9 or 11 watt (not white) LEDs are not what caused this, it was done over years by earlier bulbs that were hotter.

Comment: More than just staining. I've seen paint crack over the years from the heat of incandescent bulbs.